# url_for Build Error

Tags: python, flask, build-error

I'm new at flask and html. I get build error when I try to use action attribute in my html code and I don't have any idea why this happens.
this is my html code:

```
<div class="post">
<form method=post action="{{url_for('add_post')}}" ></a>
<input type="text" name="post" placeholder="What's happenig?" /> 
<input type="submit" value="post" class="post_button" > 
</div><!--end of class post-->
```

and my flask:

```
@app.route('/mk/add_post/<username>' , methods=['POST'])
def add_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text=request.form('post')
        user=session['username']        
        post(user , text)
        p='/mk/main/%s'%username
        return redirect(p)
```

and I get this error:

```
BuildError: ('add_post', {}, None)
```

any ideas?

Comment: as I know it should be the function name

Comment: and function arguments why it needs username??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to define your url path as `@app.route('/mk/add_post/<username>' , methods=['POST'])` as you are fetching the user name form session. This should work:

```
@app.route('/mk/add_post' , methods=['POST'])
def add_post():
    ...
```

In case you do wish to stick to `'/mk/add_post/<username>'`. Change your template to:

```
<form method=post action="{{url_for('add_post', username='mahnoosh')}}" ></a>
```

**NOTE:** Also you forgot to add username as argument.

```
@app.route('/mk/add_post/<username>' , methods=['POST'])
def add_post(username):
    ...
```

Here's how I tested:

**python script:**

```
from flask import *                                  

app = Flask(__name__)                                

@app.route('/mk/add_post/<username>' , methods=['POST'])       
def add_post(username):                              
    if request.method == 'POST':                     
        print username                               
        return username                              

@app.route('/')                                      
def main():                                          
    return render_template('so.html')                

if __name__ == "__main__":                           
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=5050)
```

**so.html:**

```
<html>                                                                        
<div class="post">                                                            
  <form method=post action="{{url_for('add_post', username='mahnoosh')}}" ></a>  
<input type="text" name="post" placeholder="What's happenig?" />              
<input type="submit" value="post" class="post_button" >                       
</div>                                                                        
</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with url_for form action

Comment: @mahnooosh, yes and it takes an input, here, username. You need to specify it.

Comment: I get this error : TypeError: add_post() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: @mahnooosh, did you use quotes when specifying the user name. Check again, it woks for me.

Comment: @mahnooosh, also you forgot to add username as argument in your function.

Comment: I did them all but I still have TypeError :(

Comment: I did these: def add_post(username)

Comment: and <form method=post action="{{url_for('.add_post', username='mahnoosh')}}" ></a>
error :TypeError: add_post() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: @mahnooosh, what about your `@app.route`? It does it contain username?

Comment: yes @app.route('/mk/add_post/<username>' , methods=['POST'])

Comment: @mahnooosh, Oh come on. this should work. Did you restart your flask server after making these changes?